# How to map any csv file to object with 1 method

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm trying to map CSV file into class object with C#. My problem is that i have 3 different files, but I want to fallow DRY principles. Can someone tell me how to change 'ParseLine' method to make it possible?

C# consol app.

This is how my FileReader looks like:

```
public class FileReader<T> : IFileReader<T> where T : Entity
    {
        private readonly ITransactionReader<T> _transactionReader;

        public FileReader(ITransactionReader<T> transactionReader)
        {
            _transactionReader = transactionReader;
        }  
        public List<T> GetInfoFromFile(string filePath)
        {
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
            var genericLines = new List<T>();
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                genericLines.Add(_transactionReader.ParseLine(line));
            }

            return genericLines;
        }
    }

public interface IFileReader<T> where T : Entity
    {
        List<T> GetInfoFromFile(string filePath);
    }
```

This is how the object should look like.

```
public class TransactionReader : ITransactionReader<Transaction>
    {
        public Transaction ParseLine(string line)
        {
            var fields = line.Split(";");
            var transaction = new Transaction()
            {
                Id = fields[0],
                Month = int.Parse(fields[1]),
                Day = int.Parse(fields[2]),
                Year = int.Parse(fields[3]),
                IncomeSpecification = fields[4],
                TransactionAmount = int.Parse(fields[5])
            };
            return transaction;
        }
    }

    public interface ITransactionReader<T>
    {
        T ParseLine(string line);
    }
```

This is how I run it for test purposes.

```
class Program
    {
        private static readonly string filePath = "C:/Users/<my_name>/Desktop/C# Practice/ERP/ERP/CsvFiles/Transaction.csv";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ITransactionReader<Transaction> transactionReader = new TransactionReader();
            IFileReader<Transaction> fileReader = new FileReader<Transaction>(transactionReader);


            List<Transaction> Test()
            {
                var obj = fileReader.GetInfoFromFile(filePath);

                return obj;
            }

            var list = Test();

        }
    }
```

I'm looking to modify that line:

```
genericLines.Add(_transactionReader.ParseLine(line));
```

and method arguments to make it open for any CSV fil.
I don't mind to change that composition into something more effective.

Comment: For structured files you should always use a well tested library - does not matter if that is your own or third party, unless it is **well tested** - and for CSV you can use [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) or [FileHelpers.net](https://filehelpers.net) - also this is totally DRY - **D**o not **R**einvent others alread**Y** solved ;o)

Comment: I strongly agree with @SirRufo. My suggestion would be to use CsvHelper; I have used it a number of times and it works well

Comment: Now I must say I agree as well. I'm begginer, so I did't even know aboute CsvHelper, but it works fine for me :) thank you for help.